# An Algorithms Homework Problem: Cells Matrix Scanning Problem

Tags: c, algorithm, loops

Instruction: Several cells are arranged one after the other in a straight line. In i-th cell, a given integer ai is written (i=1,2, …, N). I start from the first cell at the left end and move right; I can choose to jump into the next cell, or into the next of the next cell. Every time I entered a cell i, I have to pay | ai | dollars, when ai is negative, or to receive ai dollars, when ai is nonnegative. At most, how many dollars can I earn?

Input: Integer values of N, a1, a2, …., aN, separated by spaces.

Output: One integer equals to the wanted profit.

Constraints: 0 < N < 100; -100 < ai < 100 for each ai.

e.g.

Input: 7 2 -1 3 –2 -1 6 -5

Output: 10

I have made a mess of the solution. If anyone has any suggestions I will be very thankful!

This is what I got so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{
 int n,array[100];
 int i = 0;
 int sum = 0;


 if(scanf("%d",&n)){};
 for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    if(scanf("%d",&array[i])){}
 }

 for(i=0;i<n;i++)
 {
     if(array[i] >= array[i+1])
     {
        if(array[i+1] >= array[i+2])
        {
            if(array[i+2] > array[i+3])
            {
                sum += array[i+1];
                i++;
            }
            sum += array[i];
        }
        else if(array[i+1] < array[i+2])
        {
            if(array[i] >= array[i+2])
            {
                sum += array[i];
            }
            else if(array[i] < array[i+2])
            {
                sum += array[i+1];
                i++;
            }
        }
     }
     else if(array[i] < array[i+1])
     {
        if(array[i+1] < array[i+2])
        {
            if(array[i] < array[i+2])
            {
                sum += array[i+1];
                i++;
            }
            else if(array[i] >= array[i+2])
            {
                sum += array[i];
            }
        }
        else if(array[i+1] >= array[i+2])
        {
            sum += array[i];
        }
     }
 }

 printf("%d", sum);

 return 0;
}
```

What is the biggest possible sum of digits in the array within the constraints imposed by the instruction(can skip to i and i+1)?

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: The output is inconsistent. I have trouble figuring out the algorithm to solve the problem.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more as to what exactly you want from your program?

Answer (score 1):

in

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
   if(array[i] >= array[i+1])
```

when `i == n-1` you access to `array[n]` which is out of *array* or not initialized

Similar problems when you access to `array[i+2]` or `array[i+3]`

The minimal changes you can do without modifying your algorithm (I do not understand it to be frank) is to replace the second

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
```

by

```
for(i=0; i<(n-2); i++)
```

and to replace

```
if(array[i+2] > array[i+3])
```

by

```
if(((i + 3) < n) && (array[i+2] > array[i+3]))
```

---

that is very strange :

```
if(scanf("%d",&n)){};
```

I encourage you to do something like that :

```
if ((scanf("%d",&n) != 1) || (n > 100) || (n <= 0)) {
  puts("invalid number of cells");
  return 0;
}
```

---

For the rest I don't really understand what you want to compute

Comment: Perhaps also check for negative numbers - also zero

Comment: @EdHeal yes you are right, and also 0 because not very useful in that case ^^

Answer (score 0):

As far as im concerned the computer can only decide between next and the second next integer, however we don't know if the good choice at this stage will lead to a worse end, for example the sequence can be:

1 -2 -5 -40 -35 7

and here when the computer sees -2 and -5 it will choose -2 and end up with -34 as the best case scenario whereas if it were to chose -5 it could end up with -32.

so my guess is that you can't calculate the 'max sum' unless you brute force.

Comment: How do you brute force it?

Comment: Brute forcing is basically trying every possible option, i dont know if its allowed to reference a website (and for that reason i can't right now) but you can simply type "Print all possible combinations of r elements in a given array of size n" to google, enter the first website and edit the source code to print all combinations instead of just the ones with 3 elements. After you get your head around the idea, you can edit your own code accordingly.

Comment: What if there are 100 digits in the array?

Comment: Thats the problem with this question, the number of all combinations of a set of data increases exponentially (2^n to find all combinations in general, however it varies in your case) and since we can't know our answer is the best for sure, we have to find all sums to compare with eachother.